# Using a genetic algorithm, how can I create offspring based off of two neural network structures?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I have two arrays of objects that describe the structure of a neural network, how can I combine them to produce an offspring that are realistic? The "chromosomes" would look something like this:

```
chromosome = [
    [Node, Node, Node],
    [Node, Node, Node, Node, Node],
    [Node, Node, Node, Node],
    [Node, Node, Node, Node, Node],
    [Node, Node, Node, Node, Node, Node, Node],
    [Node, Node, Node],
];
```

An example node:

```
Node {
    nodesThatThisIsConnectedTo = [0, 2, 3, 5] // These numbers identify which nodes to collect output from in the preceding layer from based on their index number
    weights = [0.34, 0.33, 0.76, -0.56] // These are the corresponding weights applied to the mentioned nodes
}
```

Comment: Crossover for Neural Networks is difficult for multiple reasons. You might want to look at [NEAT](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~kstanley/neat.html), which uses a clever mechanism (historical markers) to solve the problem. The linked papers (bottom of the page) contain more information about how/why that works.

Comment: Read the original 2005 (I think) paper, it's brilliantly written and would answer all  your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better approach would be to implement a genetic algorithm search for each node's weight vector - if you're locked on using GA.

for every node there is a population of vectors, and each iteration one node changes its weight vector. This seems to me like a much sounder approach then cross-over between two full networks.